# 'Easy Template Path Hints' for WordPress?

Tags: plugins, front-end, theme-options

I would like to know which theme files are being pulled on the front end of my WordPress website.

Actually, I am trying to add/edit the tag manager tracking code, but I am not sure which header.php is loading. In my template there are two header.php files under Wordpress CMS>Appearance>Editor

Comment: Check out Query Monitor. It will show what templates are loaded (under the *Theme* section of the output) and tons more.

Comment: Query Monitor is nice, but it is too much information, as it displays all tables and firing entries from the SQL database. I am looking for something like file paths displayed in containers on each section of the page.